Modelling of a complex probability distribution combining weighted uniform and normally-distributed variables
Recently, I have been attempting to come up with an accurate probability model for a random distribution present in a video game. The process I'm seeking to model occurs as follows:

Three random items are chosen from a weighted loot table (with replacement)
Each of these items are assigned a normally-distributed size
The sizes of the three items are then compared, and the largest of the three is given to the player

In this process, I already know the probability that each item will be chosen from the loot table, and the mean and standard deviation for the size distribution of every item. How can I combine this base probability with the size distribution to find out the real probability that a certain item is chosen with size distribution taken into account?

This is about the distribution of the maximum of three independent normal variables. Are all the normal distributions identical?

I don't think you can get a nice closed-form expression for the final probability that a certain item is chosen. However, the algorithm to calculate the probabilities is straightforward. I walk through the algorithm below using R.
Central to the algorithm is that, if $n$ items have sizes distributed according to $\mathcal{N}(\mu_i,\sigma_i^2)$ (for $i\in1..n)$, item $j$ will have the largest size with probability
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\varphi\bigg(\frac{x-\mu_j}{\sigma_j}\bigg)\prod_{i\neq j}\Phi\bigg(\frac{x-\mu_i}{\sigma_i}\bigg)dx$$
Your problem requires calculating many of these integrals, for which the algorithm below uses Gauss-Hermite quadrature in order to vectorize the calculations.
# First, set things up.

library(RcppAlgos) # for `permuteGeneral`
library(matrixStats) # for `rowDiffs`
library(fastGHQuad) # for `gaussHermiteData`
library(collapse) # for `setop` and `fsum`

(seed <- sample(.Machine$integer.max, 1))
#> [1] 597992504
set.seed(seed)
n <- 20 # number of items
nodes <- 100 # number of nodes to use in the Gauss-Hermite quadrature

# Simulate items weights and size distributions.

w <- rbeta(n, 2, 2)
w <- w/sum(w) # relative item weights for selection from loot table
m <- rnorm(n) # means of item sizes
s <- rexp(n) # standard deviations of item sizes

# Enumerate all possible combinations of three items chosen from the table and
# calculate the probability of each combination.

x <- comboGeneral(n, 3, TRUE)
px <- 6/factorial(3 - rowSums(rowDiffs(x) != 0))*rowProds(`dim<-`(w[x], dim(x)))

# Check that the probabilities sum to 1.

sum(px)
#> [1] 1

# Calculate the Gauss-Hermite quadrature nodes and their transformation for
# selecting each item.

xw <- gaussHermiteData(nodes)
xw$w <- xw$w/sqrt(pi)
y <- setop(outer(xw$x, sqrt(2)*s), "+", m, rowwise = TRUE)

The $j^{\text{th}}$ column of y contains the transformed quadrature nodes for calculating the probability that the $j^{\text{th}}$ item is the largest if it is sampled from the loot table.
Next, the algorithm pre-calculates the $\Phi(\frac{x-\mu_i}{\sigma_i})$ terms to perform the quadrature.
p <- `dim<-`(pnorm(y, rep(m, each = n*nodes), rep(s, each = n*nodes)),
             c(nodes, n*n))

The first 20 columns of p contain the $\Phi(\frac{x-\mu_i}{\sigma_i})$ terms for the probability that item 1 is the largest if it is sampled from the loot table. The next 20 columns are for item 2, etc.
# Perform the quadrature calculations to approximate the integrals.

# The probability of selecting the first of the three items sampled from the
# table (each row of `x` is a possible combination of three items).
psel1 <- crossprod(p[,x[,1] + (x[,2] - 1L)*n]*p[,x[,1] + (x[,3] - 1L)*n], xw$w)
# The probability of selecting the second of the three items
psel2 <- crossprod(p[,x[,2] + (x[,1] - 1L)*n]*p[,x[,2] + (x[,3] - 1L)*n], xw$w)

# Get the final probabilities by multiplying the probability of selecting an
# item from each possible set of 3 by the probability of sampling each unique
# set of three, then summing the probabilities across items.

prob <- fsum(c(psel1, psel2, 1 - psel1 - psel2)*px, x)

# Check that the probabilities sum to 1.

sum(prob)
#> [1] 1

Compare the results to simulation. First by sampling according to weights and normal distributions, and second by directly sampling the calculated probabilities.
N <- 1e7
simsel <- `dim<-`(sample(n, 3*N, 1, w), c(N, 3))
simnorm <- `dim<-`(rnorm(3*N, m[simsel], s[simsel]), dim(simsel))
simprob1 <- tabulate(simsel[cbind(1:N, max.col(simnorm))])/N
cbind(prob, simprob1, simprob2 = tabulate(sample(n, N, 1, prob))/N)
#>           prob  simprob1  simprob2
#> 1  0.051268917 0.0508987 0.0513005
#> 2  0.029145276 0.0290562 0.0290208
#> 3  0.074707311 0.0746770 0.0746645
#> 4  0.012285546 0.0122908 0.0123021
#> 5  0.106030377 0.1054189 0.1060258
#> 6  0.003386061 0.0033911 0.0034096
#> 7  0.080655893 0.0804167 0.0807467
#> 8  0.074639765 0.0747364 0.0747642
#> 9  0.002684580 0.0026646 0.0027040
#> 10 0.089383117 0.0901889 0.0893789
#> 11 0.046758615 0.0469181 0.0467121
#> 12 0.031496828 0.0317145 0.0314021
#> 13 0.013444238 0.0134729 0.0134430
#> 14 0.051365989 0.0505667 0.0512897
#> 15 0.050839774 0.0508836 0.0508662
#> 16 0.037558616 0.0377038 0.0375602
#> 17 0.065225828 0.0653598 0.0651847
#> 18 0.068803107 0.0690695 0.0688562
#> 19 0.089140658 0.0891545 0.0891678
#> 20 0.021179503 0.0214173 0.0212009

The calculated probabilities are consistent with simulation. Next, here's a spot check on the precision of Gauss-Hermite quadrature with 100 nodes when applied to this problem.
f1 <- function(x) pnorm(x, m[1], s[1])*pnorm(x, m[2], s[2])*dnorm(x, m[3], s[3])
dput(integrate(f1, -Inf, Inf, rel.tol = 1e-14)$value)
#> 0.470335110896375
f2 <- function(x) pnorm(x, m[1], s[1])*pnorm(x, m[2], s[2])
dput(sum(xw$w*f2(sqrt(2)*s[3]*xw$x + m[3])))
#> 0.470335110896375

For convenience, here's the algorithm as a function.
ditemsel <- function(w, m, s, nodes = 100) {
  n <- length(w)
  x <- comboGeneral(n, 3, TRUE)
  x1n <- (x - 1L)*n
  px <- 6/factorial(3 - rowSums(rowDiffs(x) != 0))*
    rowProds(`dim<-`(w[x], dim(x)))
  sum(px)
  xw <- gaussHermiteData(nodes)
  xw$w <- xw$w/sqrt(pi)
  y <- setop(outer(xw$x, sqrt(2)*s), "+", m, rowwise = TRUE)
  p <- `dim<-`(pnorm(y, rep(m, each = n*nodes), rep(s, each = n*nodes)),
           c(nodes, n*n))
  psel1 <- crossprod(p[,x[,1] + x1n[,2]]*p[,x[,1] + x1n[,3]], xw$w)
  psel2 <- crossprod(p[,x[,2] + x1n[,1]]*p[,x[,2] + x1n[,3]], xw$w)
  fsum(c(psel1, psel2, 1 - psel1 - psel2)*px, x)
}

# Demonstrating
  
ditemsel(w, m, s)
#>           1           2           3           4           5           6 
#> 0.051268917 0.029145276 0.074707311 0.012285546 0.106030377 0.003386061 
#>           7           8           9          10          11          12 
#> 0.080655893 0.074639765 0.002684580 0.089383117 0.046758615 0.031496828 
#>          13          14          15          16          17          18 
#> 0.013444238 0.051365989 0.050839774 0.037558616 0.065225828 0.068803107 
#>          19          20 
#> 0.089140658 0.021179503

The function is quite fast for 20 items.
system.time(ditemsel(w, m, s))
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>    0.01    0.00    0.01


Wonderful, thank you! This comes out close enough to my simulated values that I believe I can safely chalk the remaining differences up to the variance of the simulation.
